# Simplify $(1+i^\frac{1}{2})^\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: complex-numbers

How can I simplify $\sqrt{1+\sqrt{i}}$?

I thought about making $z^2=1+\sqrt{i}$ and then $w=z^2$

But I'm not really sure

Comment: You can write $z=a+bi=\sqrt{1+\sqrt i}$, square both sides, subtract 1, and square again.  You will get two equations for $a,b$ with a number of solutions.  Note that the square root in the complex numbers is multivalued.

Comment: What's the definition of square root of a complex number? There are two values of $z$ so that $z^2 = w$.  Which one is "the" square root?

Comment: There are $2$ values of $z_1,z_2$ so that $z_1^2 =z_2^2 = i$ so we can interpret $1+\sqrt i$ as either $1+z_1$ or $1 + z_2$.  And for each of those there are $4$ values of $w_1,w_a,w_2,w_b$ so that $w_1^2 =w_a^2 =1+z_1$ and $w_2^2=w_b^2 = 1+z_2$ so there are four possible answers.

Comment: You´ve received some answer, but you haven´t accepted one of them.

Answer (score 1):

$$(1+i^\frac{1}{2})^\frac{1}{2}=(1+(e^{i\frac\pi2+i2\pi n})^\frac12 )^\frac12
=(1+e^{i\frac\pi4+i\pi n} )^\frac12$$

$$=\left(1+\cos(\frac\pi4 +\pi n)+ i \sin(\frac\pi4 +\pi n) \right)^\frac12
=(re^{i\theta})^\frac12\tag 1$$

where,
$$r=\sqrt{\left(1+\cos(\frac\pi4 +\pi n)\right)^2+\sin^2(\frac\pi4 +\pi n) }
=\sqrt{2+2\cos(\frac\pi4 +\pi n) }=2| \cos(\frac\pi8 +\frac{\pi n}2) |$$

$$ \tan\theta = \frac{\sin(\frac\pi4 +\pi n)}{1+\cos(\frac\pi4 +\pi n)} 
= \tan (\frac\pi8 +\frac{\pi n}2)\implies \theta =\frac\pi8 +\frac{\pi n}2+k\pi $$

Substitute $r$ and $\theta$ into (1),

$$(1+i^\frac{1}{2})^\frac{1}{2}
=r^\frac12 e^{i\frac{\theta}2} = \sqrt{2| \cos(\frac\pi8 +\frac{\pi n}2) |}
\>e^{i\pi(\frac1{16} +\frac{ n}4+\frac{k}2)}$$

which assumes multiple values. For the special case $n=k=0$,

$$(1+i^\frac{1}{2})^\frac{1}{2}
= \sqrt{2\cos\frac\pi8}\>e^{\frac{i\pi}{16}}
=\sqrt{2\cos\frac\pi8}\>(\cos\frac{\pi}{16} + i\sin\frac{\pi}{16})$$

Answer (score 1):

I personally think that to see what’s really going on, you do not want to use the polar representation, but rather take your own original strategy to its logical end. If you want quantitative results, the polar method is fine, but pure thought gives you qualitative information that’s just as illuminating.

Thus I would start with the innermost quantity, which you have designated $1+\sqrt i$, and call it $w$, so that $(w-1)^2=i$; then your final quantity is $\sqrt w$, so that if you call this $x$, you have $x^2=w$. Putting it all together, you have $(x^2-1)^2=i$, and we may rewrite this
$$
x^4-2x+1-i=0\,,
$$
a quartic polynomial over the Gaussian integers $\Bbb Z[i]$, and we know it’s irreducible there by Eisenstein. This means that all four roots are in some sense equally good (or bad).

If you want to have a feel for where they lie in the Wessel-Argand-Gauss plane, start with the square roots of $i$, which are $\pm\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}$, at unit distance from the origin. Adding $1$ to the root in the third quadrant gets you into the fourth quadrant, but inside the unit circle, and taking the square root of that gets you numbers in fourth and second quadrants, still inside unit circle. If you start with the $\sqrt i$ in the first quadrant, adding $1$ gets you outside the unit circle, and the two square roots are outside the unit circle, in quadrants I and III.

Answer (score -1):

Using polar coordinates $\displaystyle \sqrt{1+\sqrt{i}} = \sqrt{1+\sqrt{e^{i \pi/2}}} = \sqrt{1 + e^{i \pi/4}} = \sqrt{1 + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}} \, $ from this we have

$\displaystyle r^2 = \left( 1 + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \right)^2 = 1 + \sqrt{2} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 2 + \sqrt{2} \implies r = \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}} $

and

$\displaystyle \tan \theta  = \frac{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}{1 + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} + 1} = \sqrt{2} - 1 \implies \theta = \arctan(\sqrt{2} - 1)$

So, $\displaystyle \sqrt{1 + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}} = \sqrt{re^{i\theta}} = \sqrt{r} \, e^{i\theta/2}$

Finally, $\displaystyle \sqrt{1+\sqrt{i}} = \sqrt[4]{2 + \sqrt{2}}  \, \left( \cos\left( \frac{\arctan(\sqrt{2} - 1)}{2} \right) + i\sin\left( \frac{\arctan(\sqrt{2} - 1)}{2} \right) \right)$

We can also obtain cartesian form:

$\displaystyle a + ib = \sqrt{1+\sqrt{i}}  = \sqrt{1 + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}$ yields

$\displaystyle a^2 + b^2 +i(-2ab) = 1 + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} + i \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} \implies a^2 + b^2 = 1 + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ and $\displaystyle -2ab = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$. So we have

$\displaystyle (a-b)^2 = 1 + \sqrt{2} \,$ and $\displaystyle (a+b)^2 = 1 $ which gives $\displaystyle a = \frac{1 + \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}}}{2} $ and $\displaystyle  b = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}}}{2}$

Comment: I’m downvoting this answer because this method of not carrying the possible alternate solutions forward (1) is a bad habit and to an extent (2) has left what could be called an ugly answer that still contains nested radicals.

Comment: @gen $\displaystyle \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{i}}$ is ugly then? Also, carrying what possible alternete solutions? You mean branches of square root? Then even writing $\displaystyle \sqrt{1 + \sqrt{i}}$ is meaningless without saying which branch is used. My only mistake may be not saying that I consider the principal branch. But in any case, no matter which branch is considered, the explicit answer contains nested radicals. Because $ \sin \frac{\pi}{8} = \frac{\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2}}}{2} \text{ and even worse } \sin \frac{\pi}{16} = \frac{\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt{2}}}}{2} $ And we have to live with that!